# How do you prove that the product of 2 functions is still big O of "h"

Tags: asymptotics

This is in my homework and I'm not sure how to do it:

$f \circ g \in O(h^2) \implies f \in O(h) \text{ and } g \in O(h)$.

I get it intuitively but writing it down in proof-form is evading me.

Comment: Why is this true, intuitively?

Comment: Hint: try to find counterexamples where $g = h^2/f$.

Answer (score 0):

Can this hold if
$f = h^{3/2}$?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counterexample:

Let $f = log(n)$, $g = n^2, h = n^{3/2}$.

Then $log(n)n^2 = O(n^3)$, but $n^2 \neq O(n^{3/2})$